# How can I identify the version of a managed dll in windbg?

Tags: debugging, dll, windbg, unmanaged

I have a minidump from a customer. I want to find out the assembly versions of the loaded .NET dlls. I've already searched the internet for hours now, but cannot find a usable way. 
I have windbg and have loaded SOS extension an have the needed clr.dll and mscordacwks.

using `lm -v` only shows the unmanaged dll's. I am sure I am overlooking something very simple.

Comment: It is embedded in the unmanaged resources of the assembly, the Version resource.  The mini in "minidump" does usually prevent that from making it to your machine, minidumps are not exactly designed to work well with managed code.  Not getting the full GC heap included is another typical obstacle.  Just ask the customer for a copy or to read back your Help + About dialog.

Comment: The term minidump is rather unfortunate. Depending on the options given, it could be more complete than a full dump. Generally for managed applications /ma is ideal. You can check the type of dump with the || command.

Comment: type is shown as "user mini dump"

Answer (score 9):

WinDbg's `lm v` shows all DLLs, managed and unmanaged. On that level, an assembly is just a DLL, is just a module.

With WinDbg 6.3.9600, `lm v` even shows information whether a modules has a CLR header or not:

```
0:008> lmv m MyApp
start    end        module name
10310000 10574000   MyApp(deferred)             
    Image path: C:\...\MyApp.exe
    Image name: MyApp.exe
    Has CLR image header, track-debug-data flag not set
    Timestamp:        Wed May 21 16:34:02 2014 (537CB95A)
...
    ProductVersion:   1.8.0.44
    FileVersion:      1.8.0.44
...
```

However, the FileVersion and ProductVersion is still unmanaged information compiled into the native resource part of the DLL.

I suggest you use `!SaveModule <start address> <filename>` to save the file on disk and then use a reflection tool like [dotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/download/) to open it and get the assembly information from there, which will give you the name, version, culture and public key token.

To save all modules, [Naveen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19407/naveen) has [written a script](http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/11/12/script-to-saveallmodules-in-net-4-0-sos-within-windbg/) like this:

```
!for_each_module .if ($spat ("${@#ImageName}","*.exe")) { !SaveModule ${@#Base} c:\temp\${@#ModuleName}.exe } .else { !SaveModule ${@#Base} c:\temp\${@#ModuleName}.dll }
```

Comment: !SaveModule worked for me and i was able to get the Version from the Properties dialog Details tab

Answer (score 8):

Alright, after some more research I came to the conclusion that that kind of information is just not available for those dll's in a minidump. Anyway I was at least able to get some more information about the files, and maybe this is useful for someone else in the future.

You can get at least the metata information of the dll's, and maybe you can find something useful in there. Here's how to do that:

First get the domain:

```
!dumpdomain
```

You might end up with a large amount of listed assemblies. Now you can either look them up by hand using:

```
!dumpassembly ADDRESS
```

or you can just use the lazy way: Install the python extension for windbg (http://pykd.codeplex.com/) and use the following script for a quick overlook (it's maybe not the nicest script, but it's working and I didn't want to invest more time):

```
import pykd

def dump_assemblies():
    assemblies = 0

    addrs = pykd.dbgCommand("!dumpdomain").splitlines()
    for x in addrs:
        if x[:8] == "Assembly":
            assemblies = assemblies + 1
            print "### retrieving assembly " + x[-8:]
            print pykd.dbgCommand("!dumpassembly " + x[-8:])
    print "### found " + str(assemblies) + " assemblies."

dump_assemblies()
```

You will now be able to do a text search (CTRL + F) for the dll. Once you found it, you can find the offset next to the module name (looks something like 12327C8     C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyDLL.dll).

You can now dump the module using:

```
!dumpmodule 12327C8
```

which will lead you to:

```
Name:       C:\Program Files\MyApp\MyDLL.dll
Attributes: PEFile 
Assembly:   131a22e2
LoaderHeap:              00000000
TypeDefToMethodTableMap: 19220010
TypeRefToMethodTableMap: 134303e0
MethodDefToDescMap:      13430740
FieldDefToDescMap:       13433964
MemberRefToDescMap:      134350c8
FileReferencesMap:       13435918
AssemblyReferencesMap:   1343591c
MetaData start address:  1c1aaa4c (4248 bytes)
```

Now you can check the metadata of the dll simply with:

```
dc 1c1aaa4c 1c1aaa4c + 4248
```

That's the closest I could get to more information about the DLL. Unfortunately the file version was not written there, just some other more generic info. Anyway, I will try to get in touch with the customer again. Thanks for the answers anyway.

Comment: The metadata size is specified in decimal, so you should start write **0n**4248: `dc 1c1aaa4c 1c1aaa4c + 0n4248`. Otherwise you'll have a problem finding version number. I can't edit the answer