# How do I find image base address of a process from a crash dump in Windbg

Tags: windows, windbg, crash-dumps

I have a memory crash dump, and I can list processes with `!process 0 0`

What I want to do is find the Image Base Address of `calc.exe` and get its contents from the memory. Potentially saving it into a file.

what do I need to do to achieve that?

Edit: the type of dump I have is "automatic dump" but I would like to know the technique for other types such as full core dump

Comment: It might not be possible. The executable may have been paged out and not be in the crash dump which is physical RAM only and does not include the page file.

Comment: For user mode dumps, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24648235/480982

Answer (score 0):

a dump can be of several types
what is the type of dump is it user mode or kernel mode  ?
it is mindump of full dump ?

in many cases the pages may not be present either being paged out or intentionally discarded init section of modules

anyway
if user mode try !vadump or !address to locate the module of interest find its start address and end address and try dumping in page size increments (0x1000 bytes )using .writemem

in kmode use !vad

and follow both commands by lm or !dh to get the module information in both user mode and kernelmode

here is an user mode dump !address info

```
F:\caldump>cdb -c "!address calculator;q" -z calc.dmp | awk "/Reading/,/quit/"

0:023> cdb: Reading initial command '!address calculator;q'


Usage:                  Image
Base Address:           00007ff7`04a30000
End Address:            00007ff7`04a31000
Region Size:            00000000`00001000 (   4.000 kB)
State:                  00001000          MEM_COMMIT
Protect:                00000002          PAGE_READONLY
Type:                   01000000          MEM_IMAGE
Allocation Base:        00007ff7`04a30000
Allocation Protect:     00000080          PAGE_EXECUTE_WRITECOPY
Image Path:             C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.WindowsCalculator_10.1906.55.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\Calculator.exe
Module Name:            Calculator
Loaded Image Name:
Mapped Image Name:
More info:              lmv m Calculator
More info:              !lmi Calculator
More info:              ln 0x7ff704a30000
More info:              !dh 0x7ff704a30000
```

Comment: `!process 0 0` is a command that's only available in kernel mode, isn't it? At least I never use it in user mode.

Comment: I'm on kernel mode indeed. Can you elaborate more on usage of !vad to access process pages?

Comment: for starters take a [look here]( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/mapping-symbols-when-the-peb-is-paged-out) there is no guarentee that you would still be able to dump back the module from a dump after following this except for kernel mode critical modules like nt

Answer (score 0):

Since !process 0 0 works then it's a kernel dump. Try inspecting the peb

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-peb